# 301 redirect WITHOUT root access

Tags: apache, redirect

I did my homework about 301 redirect.

However I do *not* have root access to my previous website, because it is provided by school.

For example
www.hello.edu/people/MY-WEBSITE

I have FTP access to my own folder "MY-WEBSITE", but not the root folder.

I want to ask is it possible to perform a 301 redirect?  I tried to upload a simple .htaccess file to my folder but it did not work.

Thanks!

UPDATE: As someone recommended, this is the error message I got when I upload .htaccess file to my folder:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@XXXXXXXXX.edu and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: This is probably better suited to serverfault.com rather than stack overflow, but wherever you post the question you should try and be more specific about what you've tried so far and exactly what went wrong. "I tried a simple `.htaccess` but it did not work" - what exactly did you put in the .htaccess file, and does "did not work" mean it did nothing at all, or that it did a 302 instead of 301, or did you get a 500 error, or ...

Comment: This may be useful, it is about web browser redirects: [auto-redirect](http://www.pa.msu.edu/services/computing/faq/auto-redirect.html)